# Do any companies have comprehensive internal documentation that is public?

Tags: websites, documentation, onboarding

By comprehensive internal documentation, I mean pages / documents that explain how team members do their jobs, and one place that connects all these pages. The purpose of these are to train new team members and retain knowledge of experienced team members.

For example, [Gitlab has a Handbook](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/) that is exactly what I've described above. It contains over 3000 pages. And it covers the "how to" of nearly every single part of their huge business. However I cannot find any others like it.

Many businesses have really great "handbook documents" (such as [Valve's one](http://www.valvesoftware.com/company/Valve_Handbook_LowRes.pdf), and [Pronto's one](https://www.prontomarketing.com/employee-handbook/)), however these are single documents that are probably meant to be read over one or two days, and don't go into any detail about individual roles.

**Clarification:**
By "internal", I don't mean "private" - those are two separate things. Most software companies have public documentation that you can read that explains how to use the software they sell. It's ***for*** external readers. If they have documentation for their employees, that would be internal documentation, regardless of whether it's public (accessible) or private (not accessible).

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question here ? Gitlab has one, few if any other companies do. Are you looking for a specific part or detail of organization in these companies ?

Comment: Questions that ask for an open-ended list don't really meet the stack exchange-wide requirement for *specific answerability*.  A few sites toy with waiving that, but it does not for the most part go well, as that tends to veer toward being a *discussion forum* in contrast to the original strict Q&A goal.

Comment: Its not really Internal Documentation if its accessible by the external community is it....Most documentation available is to tell you how to use a product. Git for example, has a huge library of commands which someone might use. Likewise, C code has a library of documentation documenting the behavior of almost every function. Neither will tell you exactly how the software is actually implemented and what a developer of said product has to do.

Answer (score 2):

> Do any companies have comprehensive internal documentation that is public?

Usually, no, they do not have. That kind of information is considered part of the business secrets.

Some companies publish that information, among other reasons, because:

- they are already big enough and cannot be shaken by the competition;
- they do everything for free anyway, and everything they do is to help others;
- by mistake; they publish it unintentionally;
- others;

However, if you already found such documentation, feel free to read it and learn from it.

If you have other questions, please feel free to ask them, each one separately.

---

> **internal documentation** that is **public**

I just read it again, and I realized that you should decide: **internal documentation** or **public**? Because these terms are usually opposites.